# MSTP: choice of MSTs and "freezing" an active topology

Tags: spanning-tree

The scenario:
A network topology consiting of a few layer 2 switches with some end devices on the edges. The pairs of end devices are in the same VLAN, a spanning tree protocol like MSTP created active topologies for each of the VLANs.

Now the questions:

- Is there a way to choose the MSTs automatically so that they have as few as possible stations in common?
- Is it possible to "freeze" the active topologies (MSTs)?

For the first question, I would prefer not to split the network up into different regions.

For the second one, I maybe could stop the bridges learning process altogether (But I did not find any corresponding managed objects in the standard). Anyway, the better option would be to just make sure that no alternative paths are made because of any reasons like e.g. a temporary link failure.

Please be aware that this is a theoretical question and I can not come up with any real world hardware - so this is just about the current standards.

Thanks for reading,
Greetings.

Comment: What do you mean by "freezing the topology?" What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: With "Freezing the topology" I mean stopping the MST-Protocol from updating it.

Comment: Why don’t you turn it off?

Comment: I was afraid that this would make the current paths unavailable after some time. Aren't they affected by the ageing mechanism, since no BPDUs arrive when MSTP is disabled?

Comment: If MSTP is disabled, there's no mechanism for disabling paths.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! Do you have any advice for my other problem:
- Is there a way to choose the MSTs automatically so that they have as few as possible stations in common?

Comment: A qualified yes.  It's dependent on the switch implementation.